# Can't upload image with Angular and Netcore

Tags: angular

Code is a bit messy because I tried different things at once. It works with Postman.
Where I have in body form-data then key File.  With Angular doesn't hit the endpoint, url is fine. I am thinking parameters do not match with the netcore but I don't know why

```
 uploadImage(userId: number, file:any) {
    console.log(`${this.baseUrl}${ApiPaths.uploadPhoto}/${userId}`);

    const photoDto = {
        Url: '',
        File: file,
        PublicId: ''
    };

    const formData = new FormData();

    formData.append('url', photoDto.Url);
    formData.append('file', photoDto.File);
    formData.append('publicId', photoDto.PublicId);

    return this.http.post(`${this.baseUrl}${ApiPaths.uploadPhoto}/${userId}`, formData, {
        headers: {
          'Content-Type': 'file'
        }});
}
```

netcore code:

```
 // [Authorize]
    [HttpPost("uploadImage/{userId}")]
    public async Task<ActionResult> UploadImage(int userId, [FromForm]PhotoDto photoDto)
    {
        if (userId != int.Parse(User.FindFirst(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier).Value))
        {
            return Unauthorized();
        }

        var result = await _userService.SavePhoto(userId, photoDto);

        return CreatedAtRoute("GetPhoto", new { id = userId }, result);
    }
```

Comment: change your `content-type` to `multipart/form-data` you are not sending a file you are actually sending FormData.

Comment: still doesn't work, I also changed the variable name in the post to match the name in the netcore endpoint

Comment: Solved the issue by removing headers since I got an error, I got validation exception  with the multipart, I have no idea why it did hit the endpoint now, probably because I am stressed and can't focus properly I overlooked the debugging before adding the headers. 30 minutes well spent

Comment: It did not hit because the api signature expects a multipart formdata but you were passing content-type as file and hence they call did not match the API spec so it was not hitting the endpoint. After changing it to multipart the request meets the API spec and it hits the endpoint..